# Is it OK to use a map to pass a single key,value pair to a method instead of direct key, value passing?

Tags: java, maps

Consider the following sample program:

```
function testMap(Map m) {
    // Do something with map here
}

function testDirect(String key, String value) {
    // Do something with values here
}

Map<String, Object> properties = Collections.singletonMap("key", "value");
// Calling the function with map
testMap(properties);

// Calling function with direct values
testDirect("key", "value");
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? This would neeessly add overhead. *Unless* the map may contain many such pairs, and some are optional, and can't see the gain here.

Comment: Passing direct String key, String value will be better. Why to take overhead of importing `Map`

Comment: What do you mean by is it OK?

Comment: Does your code need exactly one key/pair value? Or does it also accept more than one? If you *always* need just one, it's not worth creating a map. But of course it depends on what you're doing in each method.

Comment: No, it's not OK, if you want to work in _my_ team.  If the method can  only ever process one entry, then writing it so that its parameter is a `Map` misleads anyone who's going to write code that calls your method, and anyone who maintains your code in the future.  You must write the signatures of all your methods in a way that accurately reflects what the methods are going to do. Having a `Map` parameter that you're using for passing a single key and value doesn't do that.

Comment: @Oleg What I mean by "OK" is whether it is a good option.

Comment: OK, apparently it was clear to other people and I think you got your response.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you don't need a Map.

I suggest you further reading if you are wondering about these issues;

KISS (Keep It Simple,Stupid)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

and YAGNI (you aren't gonna need it)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No! No way! For god sake NO!

Long answer:

Simplicity is *the* key goal for good design, doing extra work without need it is not just bad but aiming in the wrong target.

For a great explanation what simple means (no, simple is not easy) watch the [Simple Made Easy presentation](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy).